# Using a switch to convert alphabetical month to integer

Tags: c

This is a homework problem. I'm using C.

I'm inputting a month in the form of a three-letter string (Jul, Jan, Apr...), and I need to convert this input into an integer value.

I am trying to use a switch to set `m` based on the values of the inputted `char`s. The following solution is working fine except when the month entered is `JUN`, which should be converted to 6 but is instead being converted to 2:

```
char mo[] = {month[0], month[1], month[2]};  //convert the string to a char array

int m;   //declare return value

switch(mo[0]){
case 'j':
    switch(mo[2]){
    case 'n':
        switch(mo[1]){
        case 'a':
            m = 1;
            break;
        case 'u':
            m=6;
            break;
        }
    case 'l':
        m=7;
        break;
    }
case 'f':
    m=2;
    break;
```

Any idea why this doesn't work for `JUN`?

Comment: @Pubby OP should really use `strncmp`, but other than that, yes

Comment: @drewmore: Increase the warning level of your compiler. It can detect the absence of `break` statements and let you know much sooner than by going to SO :)

Comment: Incidentally, why have you marked this C++ if it's C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you did not put `break;` *after* each nested switch block.

Comment: +1 specifically `case 'n'` and `case 'j'` do not have `break` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
const char *months = "JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC,";

const char *find = "MAY";

const char *foundAt = strstr(months, find);
if (foundAt != NULL)
{
    if (foundAt[3] == ',')
    {
        printf("This is month number %d\n", ((foundAt - months) / 4) + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Not a valid month */
    }
}
else
{
    /* Not a valid month */
}
```

Uppercase your input, and you should be able to find valid months by searching the array.
If you found something then look at 3 past that position.  If it is a comma, then what you found is valid.
Calculate the difference between the point found, and the start of the months.  Divide that by 4 to give you a unique number 0 .. N.  Add 1, to get a better looking month number (jan = 1 and so on).

This is a bit easier to read and use than the switch approach.

Comment: The code above shows the concept.  One would also have to consider the cases where find is not 3 characters long, or has embedded commas, or is an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `break` statement at the end of your case block for 'j' and 'n'.

```
switch(mo[0]){
case 'j':
    switch(mo[2]){
    case 'n':
        switch(mo[1]){
        case 'a':
            m = 1;
            break;
        case 'u':
            m=6;
            break;
        }
        break;
    case 'l':
        m=7;
        break;
    }
    break;
case 'f':
    m=2;
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't *need* to use a switch statement, a quick and easy solution would be as follows. Let's say you have the month value you want to convert thus:

```
const char* month = "JUN";
```

The conversion can be done using:

```
const char* MONTHS = "JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC";
int monthNo = ( strstr( MONTHS, month ) - MONTHS ) / 3;
```

After this `monthNo` would equal 5 (i.e months being numbered 0-11) so just add 1 if you need it to be six.

Answer (score 1):

```
short int mesnum(char *mes){
    if((strcmp(mes,"Jan")==0))
        return 1;
    if((strcmp(mes,"Feb")==0))
        return 2;
    if((strcmp(mes,"Mar")==0))
        return 3;
    if((strcmp(mes,"Apr")==0))
        return 4;
    if((strcmp(mes,"May")==0))
        return 5;
    if((strcmp(mes,"Jun")==0))
        return 6;
    if((strcmp(mes,"Jul")==0))
        return 7;
    if((strcmp(mes,"Aug")==0))
        return 8;
    if((strcmp(mes,"Sep")==0))
        return 9;
    if((strcmp(mes,"Oct")==0))
        return 10;
    if((strcmp(mes,"Nov")==0))
        return 11;
    if((strcmp(mes,"Dec")==0))
        return 12;
    return 99;
}
```

```
char* nummes(short int num){
    if(num==1)
        return "Jan";
    if(num==2)
        return "Feb";
    if(num==3)
        return "Mar";
    if(num==4)
        return "Apr";
    if(num==5)
        return "May";
    if(num==6)
        return "Jun";
    if(num==7)
        return "Jul";
    if(num==8)
        return "Aug";
    if(num==9)
        return "Sep";
    if(num==10)
        return "Oct";
    if(num==11)
        return "Nov";
    if(num==12)
        return "Dec";
    return "???";
}
```

Comment: A rare use of `short int`.

Comment: it gets promoted for the equality tests.

Comment: if you compare a float to a double, the float will be 'promoted' to a double for the purposes of the compare.   Likewise, a short will be 'promoted' to an int.   That rule applies in the case above.  The value 12 is an int, therefore the short has to be promoted.

Comment: @evilteach is there a way to circunvent that ? are you saying that i am not saving precious bytes by using a short int ?

Comment: Implementations vary by compiler, but yes.  I suspect you would save bytes by passing it as an int instead.   Using shorts in a struct where you know that the value will always fit might be of benefit.   Some APIs, may demand shorts.  That is another reason to use them.   For speed, in general ints are faster than shorts.

Answer (score 0):

@Elazar already have pointed out where's your mistake. It's just  Another way to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int monthn(const char *);

int main()
{
  printf("JAN:%d,jan:%d\n",monthn("JAN"),monthn("jan"));
  return 0;
}

int monthn(const char *name)
{
  const char *months[] = { "JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC" };
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(months)/sizeof(months[0]); i++) 
    {
      if(strcmp(months[i], name) == 0) 
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

This output:

```
JAN:0,jan:-1
```